# Test returning more assertions than expected

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I've watched a video on TDD and thought to give it a try. I've set up 2 very basic tests and they are both working fine, returning the results I expect. The question is, why is the second test returning 2 assertions? The first returns a single assertion as I expected.

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_see_the_landing_page()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

/** @test */
public function a_user_who_isnt_signed_in_is_redirected_to_login()
{
    $response = $this->get(route('home'));
    $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));
}
```

Running this test file gives:

> PHPUnit 7.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>      .. 2 / 2 (100%)
>      Time: 187 ms, Memory: 14.00MB
>      OK (2 tests, 3 assertions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [`assertRedirect`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L145) actually does two assertions internally. One to check [if the status code is a redirect code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L147) and one to see [if the redirected url is correct](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6bdf8af7790db485856ecde0448b353d0cb15ca/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php#L152).

Comment: Thanks, will look out for similar on the other tests I make :)